# Style в body

Tags: html, css

Можно ли помещать тег <style> в теге <body>, или обязательно в <head>? Если нет, то почему? Ведь работает же.

Comment: head загружается первее чем боди,есть шанс что не подгрузится что то.

Comment: при маленькой скорости соединения и разрывах соединения

Comment: видимо, просто браузеры закрывают на это глаза. Пропустите Вашу страницу через [валидатор](<http://validator.w3.org/>). Думаю, он все расскажет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашлись ответы на SO

- [Does STYLE have to be in the HEAD of an HTML document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303416/does-style-have-to-be-in-the-head-of-an-html-document)
- [Why can’t style tags within the HTML body tag validate on W3C? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803518/why-cant-style-tags-within-the-html-body-tag-validate-on-w3c)

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите, как мейл переделывал главную: http://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/142193
В самом начале статьи рассказывается о том, как используется контейнер style:

```
<style>
    /* mailbox styles */
</style>
<div class="mailbox">
    <!-- mailbox HTML -->
</div>
<script>
    // mailbox JS
</script>
```